# Bazaar: moving from single-developer to an accessible repository

Tags: bazaar

I've started using bazaar DVCS for a project in a single-user mode, as described in their tutorial. I would like to involve another developer in this project, but the multi-user, "brancheable" repository seems to have different structure from my little ad-hoc directory. I can't find the documentation on how to go from one to the other. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how you managed to get something that's not branchable. It's a fundamental thing in bazaar.

Suppose you have done something like this for your code:

```
c:\dev> bzr init proj
c:\dev\proj> hackhackhack.bat
c:\dev\proj> bzr commit
```

This should be a branchable repository. i.e.

```
c:\dev2> bzr init-repo .
c:\dev2> bzr branch c:\dev\proj proj
```

You now have a branch.

If you're talking about running the built-in server, you need to do this:

```
c:\dev2> bzr serve
```

Comment: OK, so I see 

    bzr init-repo .

is needed on the new location before I can make a branch. Good to know. Does your advice still apply if I've never done 

bzr init-repo c:\dev 

?

Comment: The only thing init-repo does is sets up a folder at that level that lets you share files between multiple branches inside that folder.. for example if you have c:\dev2\proj and c:\dev2\proj-featurebranch, it won't take up 2x the hard disk space for the repository.

Comment: Ahh, FryGuy - this is what I needed to know. Thank.